# how to continuously trying to connect with a socket till it come up?

Tags: python, sockets

I am having a python socket client program. what I need to do is my client should wait for server to be available for connection then connect with the server. any Idea to get this?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is to run [`socket.connect_ex()`](https://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect_ex) in while loop, something like (assuming you want to use tcp)

```
import socket
from time import sleep
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
while s.connect_ex(("10.0.0.1", 80)) != 0:
    sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a function that connects to the server then wrap it using decorator. This will keep the two different logic of connecting to the server and retrying separate, which can be a better way to maintain your code.

However, this could be a bit of an overkill and could end up over complicating the code if you are only going attempt to reconnect to the server once, but if other functions within the code require reattempting, I would highly recommend using the decorator since it can 
reduce redundancy in the code.

```
def solve_issue():
    sleep(10)

def attempt_reconnect(func,*args,**kwargs):
    MAX_RETRY=2
    for i in range(MAX_RETRY):
        try:
            return_value=func(*args,**kwargs)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("error"+str(e))
            return_value=e
            solve_issue()
    return return_value

@attempt_reconnect
def connect_to_server():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```